# How to create eclipse plugin to checkout project and configure it

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, oomph

I want to automate the project check out and configuration, for that I am trying to create plugin. I tried to search the web but no luck so far.
I have started with the basic example templates but how to code checkout and configuration, can't figure out. Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use [Eclipse Oomph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring) for that ([here is an old SVN check-out example](https://github.com/nonfuncter/oomph-svn-checkout/blob/master/OomphSVNCheckout.setup)).

Comment: @howlger Thank you for your response. could you please tell me how to use the OomphSVNCheckout.setup file provided in the example and what needs to modify as per my project.

Comment: Follow the [_Eclipse Oomph Authoring_](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring) documentation. If you get stuck and a web search with the keyword _oomph_ doesn't help, ask a question tagged with [oomph].

Comment: @howlger I tried a lot to understand but really i am confused. i have created new question too but no luck so far.. could you please assist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58515439/need-help-in-oomph